# singleton example how works

Tags: c++, singleton

I've found this singleton example in C++ language:

```
#include <iostream>

class singleton {
private:
    // ecco il costruttore privato in modo che l'utente non possa istanziare direttamante
    singleton() { };
public:
    static singleton& get_instance() 
    {
            // l'unica istanza della classe viene creata alla prima chiamata di get_instance()
            // e verrà distrutta solo all'uscita dal programma
        static singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    bool method() { return true; };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << singleton::get_instance().method() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But, how can this be a singleton class?

Where is the control of only one istance is created?

Do not miss a static attribute?

What happens if in main function I write another get_instance() call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-instance control is done using the function-scope static inside `get_instance`. Such objects are constructed once upon program flow first passing through them and destructed at program exit. As such, the first time you call `get_instance`, the singleton will be constructed and returned. Every other time the *same object* will be returned.

This is often known as the [Meyers singleton](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point you to a rather [general description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) of the pattern and then to a [deeper dissertation](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) with a [C++ example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/2).
It seems to me more effective than trying to explain (once more again).

P.S.
And yes, you need some static definition too.